# Почему в базу данных приходит время в формате 1970-01-01?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, дата, java-8

При попытке сохранить объект в базу данных в нее приходит время в формате 1970-01-01!
Когда пытаюсь сохранить через REST  клиент объект в бд:
Пример объекта

```
 Employee employee = new Employee("Джордж", "Буш", 1, "Sales", Gender.FEMALE, new Date(11-10-1988));
```

То в базу данных поле с датой приходит 1970-01-01.
Везде импортированы пакеты import java.sql.Date;
Когда сохраняю через Postman, то все нормально
В чем может быть проблема? Почему приходит такое время?
Поле Date в классе выглядит так!

```
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

Comment: `11-10-1988` равно `-1987` — что-то мне подсказывает, что это не то, что вы хотели

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как я должен ввести корректные данные? Что мне нужно сделать?

Comment: любая строка должна быть в кавычках. Цифры без кавычек воспринимаются как числа и работают операторы вычитания

Comment: И кстати формат дат в postgresql вообще не имеет значение. Когда вы пишите `new Date()` это функция java и соответственно формат передачи дат надо использовать тот, который принимает эта функция в джаве

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-java/ тут написано, что по умолчанию даты в java задаются в формате YYYY-MM-DD. Кроме того посмотрите описание класса Date https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: я писал в этом YYYY-MM-DD формате, разницы не какой, в базу данных приходит 1970-01-01

Comment: так вы же пишите `new Date(11-10-1988)` java сначала вычисляет выражение `11-10-1988` а потом результат передает в `new Date(-1987)`. Вот если бы вы написали `new Date("11-10-1988")` то тогда бы это была строка

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать написать вместо `new Date()` саму строку `"1988-10-11"` тогда по идее postgresql сам переведет в дату. Ну это конечно если драйвер работы с БД у java это позволяет

Comment: new Date(1988-10-11) -  в БД приходит 1970-01-01

new Date(11-10-1988)-  в БД приходит 1970-01-01

new Date("1988-10-11") - класс Date перечеркивает компилятор и ошибка вылетает при звпуске IlleagalArgument Exeption

"1988-10-11" - конструктор принимает Date а не стринг

Comment: Да бред какой-то !!!!!!!
просто как мне корректно передать дату в поле день рождения?
Может я не тем классом пользуюсь?

Comment: По ссылке которую я дал посмотрите, там все написано, какие конструкторы есть у даты. И еще обратите внимание на Depricated который почти у всех из них под которым написано как теперь принято задавать даты (Через сторонние классы, например DateFormat.parse(String s))

Comment: Вот что выдал гугл по запросу "дата в java" https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1941-kak-ne-poterjatjhsja-vo-vremeni--datetime-i-calendar